# UITapGestureRecognizer breaks UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath in SearchField Class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using this **library** for SearchText Field

https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField

Here is my Code :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismissKeyboard")))


}

func dismissKeyboard()
{
    ClientList.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Dismiss of keyboard is working but the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not getting called so i am not able to select anything

Image for Reference : [image]

Partial Solution I Done:

```
func hideKeyboard(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(ClientList.tableView)
        let indexPath = ClientList.tableView!.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)

        if indexPath != nil {
            return
        }
        if ClientList.becomeFirstResponder() {
            ClientList.resignFirstResponder()
        }

    }
```

But now issue is i have other list too , how can i implement for other list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue like this

**ViewDidLoad**

```
self.tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewTapped:")
self.tap.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.tap)
```

**Function**

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view != nil && touch.view!.isDescendantOfView(self.tableView) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Just updating the function to **Swift 3**

`func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view != nil && touch.view!.isDescendant(of: self.tableView) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Who's the target of the gesture? I think it should be the list since it is what you tap and it is above the view

Comment: I am tapping outside of ViewController and TableView is another Class, I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Add this to viewDidLoad

And add this function

```
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Please check the question again , i have edited it . I have got partial solution.

Comment: Your code is not clear can you make it a bit clearer